# Minimum edges removed to turn a strongly connected graph into an acyclic graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, dag, directed-graphs, connected

If I start with a directed graph that is strongly connected, is there a straightforward way / algorithm to find the smallest set of edges to remove, such that the result is a directed but acyclic graph?

To be clear, the result is neither necessarily a tree (could have more than one way from A to B), nor is the graph still connected, could have disconnected components. I just can't have cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic NP-complete problem called [Feedback Arc Set](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_arc_set).

The problem is solvable in fixed parameter tractable time $k^{O(k)}$, and there is an approximation algorithm, however it's open whether there is a constant factor approximation.

The word *feedback* refers to a cycle in a graph, and the problem is "hitting" all cycles with as few arcs (directed edges) as possible.

Note that deleting an arc is equivalent to reversing it(!)

In so-called tournament graphs (compete digraphs), the problem is slightly easier. In undirected graphs, the problem is MST.